# CGFloat addition bug?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, cgfloat

I was trying to add some CGFloat values recursively in my program. And I just realized in one particular scenario the total generated was incorrect. To ensure I had nothing wrong in my program logic, I created a simple example of that scenario (see below) and this printed the same wrong value.

```
CGFloat arr[3] = {34484000,512085280,143011440};
CGFloat sum = 0.0;
sum = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2];

NSLog(@"%f",sum);

int arr1[3] = {34484000,512085280,143011440};
int sum1 = 0.0;
sum1 =  arr1[0] + arr1[1] + arr1[2];

NSLog(@"%d",sum1);
```

The first NSLog prints 689580736.000000...while the correct result 689580720. However the second NSLog prints the correct result. I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`CGFloat` is a single precision float on 32 bit targets such as iOS - it only has a 23 bit mantissa, i.e. around 6 - 7 significant digits. Use a double precision type if you need greater accuracy.

You should probably read David Goldberg's [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) before proceeding much further with learning to program.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the answer. I thought it had to do with some limit issue. Your note clarified it. I changed it from CGFloat to double and it printed the right result. Also based on other information I just read - float has 7 digit limit, double - 15/16 and decimal - 28/29 digit limit. Thanks for the article too, I will read it at leisure.