# How come CGFloat is making up significant digits?

Tags: ios, math, cgpoint, digit, cgfloat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CGFloat addition bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302384/cgfloat-addition-bug)

I have a CGPoint (which is just a struct around two CGFloats).  Can someone explain to me how these two lines of code:

```
player.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x + 12.8f, player.position.y + 12.8f);
NSLog(@"%f,%f", player.position.x, player.position.y);
```

are generating this output:

```
828.799988,236.800003
841.599976,249.600006
854.399963,262.399994
867.199951,275.199982
879.999939,287.999969
892.799927,300.799957
905.599915,313.599945
```

The starting values for the point is (816, 224);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with float values here. That means there will be error of that margin. If you want to round to a certain number of decimal places, use the following code:

```
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", theFloat];
```

The above code rounds to 1 decimal place, which is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

`CGFloat` is either a IEEE 754 single- or double-precision floating point number, which suffers from [well-known accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). What you're seeing is an effect of that.